# openni rviz not working

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello.

I was trying to install openni_kinect on ROS in order to use NXT robot with the kinect.
However, I faced this problem with the Rviz software. adding of PointCloud2 display but there is nothing in the "topic" directory to choose from.

So right now the display screen in Rviz is just blank grey colour.

what is the cause for this problem and how do I fix it?

Thank you. (:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9435/openni-rviz-not-working/) by [Kinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/263/kinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check if you've set the fixed frame and target frame fields correctly.
If you set both of them to openni_camera then you should definitely be able to see something.

---

Originally posted by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) with karma: 284 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First things first. Confirm that:

1. You have launched: **`roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch`**
2. openni_node is publishing data: **`rostopic list`** should return a number of topics being published called /camera/*

After confirming on both, read and do as it says on the [openni_camera wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera), paragraph 3 especially. If something goes wrong, let know what exactly it was.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1